# What is the protocol used for intranet server?

Tags: windows, active-directory, django, intranet

I work as web developer in a big corporate company, and recently they did a couple of changes to proxy and network ruling, lots of services are no longer usable, and they haven't disclosed what was changed.

I used to run a django development server in my machine, and my colleagues could access it by going to `my_machine_name.intranetdomain.com` , but after these changes I can only access it through my machine.

I know for a fact the request isn't even reaching my computer

My question is, what is the protocol they started barring? So we at least know where to start

The error that appears on Chrome is `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Worth noting that this isn't even close to my area of expertise, so excuse me if I said something wrong

Comment: As noted below, your IT department is going to need to be involved here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer is "ask your network administrator", however I have an idea what the issue could be.

You likely have a corporate proxy server that all web browsers are configured to use. This proxy server likely caches resources and prevents users going to sites they don't want you to use, such as email, dropbox, etc.

My best guess is they changed the settings on the proxy server, or changed the proxy configuration, so it no longer routes requests locally.

Some possible ways around this are

- Configure the web browser to stop using the proxy server
- Add an exception to the proxy server / configuration
- Install a web browser that isn't mandated to use this proxy server

Note that some or all of these are likely to violate some corporate policies. You should ensure you have appropriate authorization before doing any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Web traffic, unless you specify a different prefix or port manually.

```
HTTP = Protocol: TCP - Port: 80
HTTPS = Protocol: TCP - Port: 443
```

I normally do not like referring people to the next person in the chain, but this REALLY needs to go through your company IT dept. If they pushed out the changes, you will likely not be able to change them back without their assistance.

Connection refused is typically a firewall issue, but it could be proxy related as well.

Comment: Yep. Ask IT. This sort of thing is their responsibility to set up and maintain (or refuse for a good reason).

Answer (score 0):

First issue is did something change on your end ? No longer listening on your LAN address and only on localhost, etc.  New firewall policy being pushed down by domain controller/etc?

Then you would be looking at addressing.  Does yourcomputername.company.com still resolve to the address your computer actually has?  Does it resolve that way on other computers?  IE, things could be great BUT that name is resolving to the wrong address... Errors would be "can't find server named ..." or "dns resolution" if the name isn't look-up-able at all and you'd need to check what address it does resolve to separately...

Last check is routing. Many sub-netted networks do not allow packets to travel between "client" subnets, only from client to "server" subnets and then out to the world.  Can someone on the same subnet connect to you? Can you connect to others on other subnets?  Routing issues typically give a different error message (no route to host)